# Sending email from php and mysql - avoid duplicate but join in one message

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on the code that would ultimately send e-mails to people matched to each other in terms of interests and other parameters.
In general, the database has already been built, the queries also get the effect that satisfies me, i.e. people who match each other in the answer.
Here I will present briefly what the cut base looks like and the query displaying users who are matched to each other:
[DB FIDDLE LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cae2e07eac3719ec0aa3b816b601554d)

Then, for preview purposes, it uses a query on my site that looks something like this:
PHP + HTML:

```
    <a href="send.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right">SEND EMAIL'S!</a>
    <?php
     include_once 'connection.php';
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select 
     m.id, m.name, m.email,
     f.id, f.name, f.email
     from
     choices c 
     join choices s 
     on c.chooser = s.choice
     left join users m on m.id = c.chooser
     left join users f on f.id = c.choice
     where s.chooser = c.choice
     and m.gender = 'M'
     and f.gender = 'F'");
    ?>
    
    <?php
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    ?>
    
    <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
     <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
     $i=0;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["0"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["1"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["2"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
    </td>
```

In response, I get:

```
| id | name | email | | id | name | email |
| -- | ---- | ----- |-| -- | ---- | ----- |
| 203 | TOM W | tomw@gmail.com || 101 | KATE B | kateb@gmail.com |
| 204 | MARK K | markk@gmail.com || 101 | KATE B | kateb@gmail.com |
| 204 | MARK K | markk@gmail.com || 102 | ALEX S | alexs@gmail.com |
```

**Now for my problem.**
Is there anyone able to show an example of how to press the SEND EMAIL'S (send.php) Send an email to all of their matches (both male and female), but if any of these people have more than one match I would like to avoid sending two emails to the same person, just include all their matches in one body
What e-mails do I expect?

First email:

```
From: MyEmail@gmail.com
To: tomw@gmail.com
Subject: Got a match!
Body:
Congratulations TOM W!, we matched you with:
KATE B (kateb@gmail.com)
```

And this is not a problem ... But the problem arises when sending an email to KATE B, who already has two matches: TOM W and MARK K.

```
From: MyEmail@gmail.com
To: kateb@gmail.com
Subject: Got a match!
Body:
Congratulations KATE B, we matched you with:
TOM W (tomW@gmail.com)
MARK K (markk@gmail.com)
```

And further, the message to MARK K will contain two people in the body because he has two matches, both with Kate B and Alex S (one message with two matched people) and Alex S in the body will have only one person, which is MARK K.

Is anyone able to show such universal code written in php that will send e-mails as described above?

Comment: It sees that your first order of business should be grouping matches by user, likely into an array with the user's IDs as the keys, so you have something like `$users[203] = [...match1data, ...match2data]`. From there, it'll be easy enough to build your emails.

Comment: Always try to break the problem down: your current problem isn't about emails, and isn't about database queries, so put all that code aside for a moment. Your current problem, as Markus AO says above, is about taking an array with one entry per match, and transforming it into an array with one entry per user.

Comment: Incidentally, have you considered homosexual people?